# Restore data from an HP StorageWorks MSA crash

Tags: backup, data-recovery

I have an HP StorageWorks (MSA 2012fc) and it has been used for production for a while.
I used parted to set up three 0x83 partitions on it.
After a power off, my Linux box attached to the MSA via fiber channel become enable to see any partitions. And when i do dmesg i get that there are only a volume named as sda ?
Also, when i list the dev directory, there are only /dev/sda.
All partitions are absent, please can you explain what happened,
and how can i restore the hole of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I can't tell you what happened but you can look for clues yourself, look at your logs - sounds like something reinitialised the volumes - I know that model of MSA and even if it did 'die' and damage your disks it wouldn't delete three partitions and create a new linux-format one for you, it would be all or nothing. As for data restoration, I'd suggest restoring from backup, I'm highly doubtful that you could restore the data on the array and I wouldn't then trust it anyway.